# Preventing Cross-Site Request Forgery Attacks With a Windows Client Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I develop an web application by `web api2`.

My client application is a windows application that developed by C# , .net 4.0.
The client application sends some Json data to the web api application and the application stores data in database.

Now the issue is sending the request with another method except my application and sending dump data to the server.I have authentication on the server but it isn't enough,I need some tokens for handling this issue.

After some searches i find [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks) and read it, but the client is a web application.
Could i use this method in my windows client app?how?

Comment: What authentication mechanism are you using?  And why is it not sufficient?

Comment: I have individual authentication and each client has username and password in the client app, but if the client use some sniffers line Fiddler2, he can find the valid request and use it to send dump data and i cannot prevent it.

Comment: So you're sending the authentication details as clear text? Not very secure at all

Comment: And what the difference if i encoding them or not???
If the hacker sends the encoded value i cannot prevent it, not any difference at all.

Comment: I never said encoding the username/pass did I, I asked if your passing them as clear text.  Which clearly you are, so even your website is sending them as clear text, correct?

Comment: @3dd I send them to the server in a json request to the server.

Comment: @SamanGholami ok so the website is also not secure. Have you considered encrypting the traffic using SSL?

Comment: No, using SSL handling this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bottom line: You shouldn't need to.

By definition, [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) attacks can only affect client applications that share cookies across domains. e.g. if you visit `www.bank.com` with your browser and then open another tab to `www.evil.com`, if `www.bank.com` does not protect against CSRF then `www.evil.com` may be able to POST a form submission to `www.bank.com` while you are logged in and then transfer money by forging the request to the `form`'s `action` URL on the transfer money page.

If your client is a Windows application, the HTTP client should not have cookies stored for any other service other than your web API.

Note that the above only applies to when cookies are used as the session management mechanism (i.e. not Kerberos, NTLM, Basic Auth, etc).

> .I have authentication on the server but it isn't enough

This should be enough as an attacker cannot forge a HTTP request to your API that will be sent along with the victim's cookies as the cookies are separated due to there being different instances of web clients. Much like being logged into Google on Chrome, but then accessing Google on Firefox - you will not share the same logged in session.

Of course, protect your API with HTTPS so the information is encrypted whilst in transit. Note that this does not protect against decompilation of your source code, which is something that is not easy to prevent. At the end of the day you cannot trust clients that are not under your control. You can make it difficult, but not impossible to prevent someone working out or changing what is being sent to your API.

Answer (score 1):

Cross site anti-forgery tokens are a form of authentication. It authenticates the client who's sending the request: the client has to visit a certain page to get the token from the server, so it cannot be any client who has not visited that page and some how just send random data to that server.

The purpose of authentication is for the server to authenticate the client (other way around is also possible, but let's forget that for the moment). You setup the system such that it is very difficult for others to pretend to be your Windows Form app. Note it can be very difficult, but theoretically it's always possible to fake. So the aim is to setup an auth such that an attacker considers it impractical to launch an attack.

This auth should not be mixed up with the authentication to verify the human user. They are different. An app can provide a UI for human users to login, but the app is not written by you. So you need to authenticate 2 things:

1. the request actually comes from your app, if that succeeds, then
2. the human user is who he claims he is, otherwise
3. reject the request

Comment: Thank you for your reply, to detecting that the request comes from my win app, how should i implement it?the solution in my mind is sending an encoded value in the request to the server but if the client inspect the requests he find it.

Comment: You can encrypt values, that can identify the caller. Maybe if each installation of the windows app is branded with information that is unique, or maybe the caller's IP, you can take that information, encrypt it and send it to the server. The server then tries to decrypt it (if it can, it is a good sign, because no one tempered with the encrypted string) and compare the information - for instance the IP from the encrypted value - with the IP of the caller. Now if someone inspects the value and uses it, his IP and the IP in the encrypted value will not match.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer It isn't good solution because my client doesn't have static IP, also if i encrypting the values and someone only copy the values and send them to the server i cannot prevent it.

Comment: You can lookup how SSL works. SSL is designed to verify the server, with the option to verify client as well. Once you understand how it works, you can either use it or implement your own auth based on the same principles. E.g. the server sends an encrypted message to the client, the client has to decrypt it and send it back to the server. If the auth works, generate a token for your trusted client so you can tell who's who.

Comment: @SamanGholami IP was just an example to visualize the idea. If someone would copy the string and sends it, then the sender will not have the same IP like that one, that is found in the encrypted string. It doesnt matter if he has a static IP or not.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer I cannot trust the owners of the application, so maybe the hacker that copy the string using the computer that i submitted as valid IP.I try to using Mac-Address but totally this idea not prevent dumping completely.thank you anyway.

Comment: @kayson I think SSL verifying client is difficult to setup and initialize for the users that using client application, i need a very simple user experience because i have many clients

Comment: Client side SSL cert is transparent to the user. It will not have any impact on the user experience.