# One AntiForgery token for all requests

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication, token, asp.net-web-api

I have Web API 2 web service with methods:

```
// Makes and returns Token by login/password.
string GetToken(string login, string password);

// Returns orders of current account.
Order[] GetMyOrders();
```

I want to authenticate user in GetMyOrders() by him Request to this method.

Request has to contain Token which will be mapped to accountId on the web-service side.

Client will use this Token for each Requests.

Can I implement GetToken() method using ASP.NET Identity?

And what is right way to authenticate using this Token and ASP.NET Identity? Can I use ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute or something else?

GetToken() will work only through https, but GetMyOrders() will work through http.

Comment: Is your API part of an ASP.NET MVC site or stand-alone?

Comment: It is stand-alone web-service. It does not have any web-views.

Comment: `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` is used to prevent [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)), [not usually required for an API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24586323/413180).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can implement OAuth Bearer Tokens in webapi.

Example below:

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

The best way to authenticate the token is built-in, which means that you will only need to put the `[Authorize]` data annotation.

So basically you should use [Owin middleware](http://owin.org/) which will allow you to use OAuth Bearer token authentication.